# How do I add my own custom header key/value on TWebHttpRequest?

Tags: delphi, http-headers, request-headers, tms, tms-web-core

I've placed a non-visual `TWebHttpRequest` component onto my form and there is a `Headers` property where I can see and change some of the default headers:

[image: TWebHttpRequest Headers in Delphi]

But there doesn't seem to be a way to add my own custom header key/value to it.

This [link](https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/components/twebhttprequest/) shows a String List Editor for Headers, but I don't seem to have that on my side:
[image]

This is what I have on my side:
[image]

How would I go about adding my own custom `Headers`?

Comment: I see the property `Headers` clearly on your last picture, just two lines above `Name`.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes, but how do I add a custom header pair to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom headers during run-time using `WebHttpRequest.Headers.AddPair` like this:

```
WebHttpRequest.Headers.Clear;

WebHttpRequest.Headers.AddPair('custom-header','whatever');
WebHttpRequest.Headers.AddPair('Content-Type','application/json');
```

I haven't figured out how to add custom headers during design-time yet though. Maybe someone else can answer that.